# how to access angular-ui-boostrap's checkbox text

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I'm writing e2e tests with protractor and now i want to check a text written next to a checkbox, but i can't figure out the right locator to access the text.

the html snippet looks like this (example from [angular-ui-boostrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap) page):

```
<label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="oneAtATime">
    Open only one at a time
 </label>
```

i am able to locate the input element itself by `.model('oneAtATime')`, but how to check for the 'Open only one at a time' text?

`getAttribute('value') returns 'true'` (because it's checked)

both `getText()` and `getInnerHtml()` are returning `empty strings`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just if someone else is struggeling with angular-ui-bootstrap checkbox, here my solution to get the text:

```
expect(element(by.css('label.checkbox')).getText()).toEqual('Open only one at a time');
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple way would be a pass `$event` to the `ng-click` event of your `input/label`

#### Markup

```
<label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="oneAtATime" ng-click="getCheckboxText($event)">
    Open only one at a time
</label>
```

#### JavaScript

```
$scope.getCheckboxText = function(event){
   var parent = event.target.parentNode;
   console.log( parent.innerText );
};
```

#### Plunk

http://plnkr.co/edit/47dqv0Bbnsp9Q3pqALVR?p=preview

Comment: i don't want an extra event registered for every checkbox i have, just to find an element in my tests. i could add an id, but i don't want to add css, scripts etc. just for my tests if i don't have to. adding an event would cost a lot of ressources, especially nested inside ng-repeat.

Comment: Realistically, adding a click handler for each input would not really be that expense, but that's neither here nor there. Why don't you include your test .js so we can see what's going on.

Comment: well okay, not 'a lot'. but the event would cost ressources, that i wouldn't need, if i could figure out how to write the right locator. i could locate the label, and parse it's text with a regular expression (just guessing, i am currently not at work), but there must be a better way. btw, many thanks for your help =)